# Add a condition to show menu link in YML

Tags: 8, users, services

how should I do if I need to show to a link menu based on a condition ?

This is my YML for my menu link :

```
double_vue_klesia.backuserswitch:
  title: 'Retour user précédent'
  menu_name: navigation-principale
  description: 'Switch back to your user account.'
  route_name: double_vue_klesia.backuser.switch
  weight: 1
```

I want to show this link only :

```
if (\Drupal::service('userswitch')->isSwitchUser())
```

This is in PHP, but I need this to be on YML (unless there a way to intercept it in php and hide it ?).

If my isSwtichUser is true (from my service), I want to show the link. But I can find a way to do it.

EDIT :

I'm using this module : https://www.drupal.org/project/userswitch

I "just" need to display a link to go back to the original user (link accessible from my frontend)

Comment: You show/hide menu links by allowing/denying access to the target route. So the first (now deleted) answer of @QuanLee is correct.

Comment: I tried was @QuanLee says, but it wasn't working :/

Comment: Can be another issue. You need to add cache data. Don't know the cache dependencies of the userswitch service, so until you know you can disable caching with `AccessResult::forbidden()->setCacheMaxAge(0)`. But better find the correct caching data for the service, with cache max age = 0 you disable a lot of caching on your page, which is bad for performance. Btw. you need to add caching also in your latest edit for a normal link if it depends on a condition.

Comment: My toolbar will still be not accessible, right, even with setCacheMaxAge(0) ? It there a way otherwise to create an "temporary toolbar" where there's only my link ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add custom access on route_name: double_vue_klesia.backuser.switch

```
double_vue_klesia.backuser.switch:
  path: '/path-of-you'
  defaults:
    _form:  '\Drupal\my_module\Form\DemoForm'
    _title: 'title'
  requirements:
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\my_module\Controller\ApplicationController::accessCustom'
```

Inside \Drupal\my_module\Controller\ApplicationController:

```
 /**
   * Check user has permission.
   *
   * @return \Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult
   */
  public function accessCustom() {
    if (if (\Drupal::service('userswitch')->isSwitchUser())) {
      return AccessResult::allowed();
    }
    return AccessResult::forbidden();
  }
```

Comment: I believe your answer is for routing.yml, I need for links.menu.yml. If i'm wrong, can you explain ?

Comment: ou can still go for the _custom_access, but you need a event subscriber to change the requirement of the existing route. Read this for a start: https://www.drupal.org/node/2187643

Comment: My link is still appearing on my front office every time.

Comment: @Quan this is the right approach so I’ve undeleted it

Comment: I see (but too late...) that I've already this method in my module, but for a toolbar and I don't have access to this when I switch my user